# How do you expose a property (DependencyProperty) of a control that is part of a user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have added several customised buttons to a user control that I'm creating.  On some of these buttons I would like to expose their visibility property to the end user allowing them to decide whether or not they wish them to be visible.  How does one go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to expose a bool property and then translate it to Visibility in your control's code?

Comment: That's what I had been thinking about, unless there was a way to expose the actual visibility property of the button(s) themselves.

Comment: Please see my answer and see if it fixes your problem

Comment: Sorry I posted c# code but let me know if you need that converting to vb

Comment: Hi Krishna, the code doesn't convert , but I know why so that won't be a problem. Presumably though I would need to replicate this for each button to which I wish to expose a visibility property?

Comment: Yes it wont convert because of the custom class name that I have used for testing. Yes you would have to use this for every control that you have got. But can I ask why you would even need this in the first place? If you derive from a 'Control' then your control should have a visibility property available directly and if you want to bind to your viewmodel, you simply use a valueconverter and use it in the xaml to show and hide your control.

Comment: Hi Krishna, you're correct in that the control itself has a visible property, but the control is made up of a series of buttons (I'm building a data navigation control) and some of those buttons (Cancel, delete, remove for example) the end user may want to hide. If you happen to have a vb conversion would you mind posting that as well, I'm close but not quite there. Thanks

Comment: I posted my attempted vb convertion in my answer. Can you let me know if it works please?

Comment: Hi Krishna.  Your Vb doesn't actually work, partly because there is a mixture of vb and c~ but also because the initial property declaration fails (Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to System.Windows.DependencyProperty).  Does your code actual compile in C#?

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it. And also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deriving your custom/user control from a button then Visibility property should be available in the xaml directly without any changes. But if you want to create a dependency Property then you can follow this approach

```
public bool ShowHide
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowHideProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowHideProperty, value); }
        }



public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHideProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHide", typeof(bool), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(true,OnShowHideChanged));

        private static void OnShowHideChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyControl c = d as MyControl;
            if(c!=null)
            {
                if((bool)e.NewValue == true)
                {
                    c.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
                }
                else
                {
                    c.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
```

and in your xaml you can do

```
<controls:MyControl ShowHide="true" ..../>
```

EDIT VB Convertion

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ShowHideProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHide", GetType(Boolean), GetType(MyClass), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(False, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf onShowHideChanged)))


    Public Property ShowHide() As Boolean
        Get
            Return CBool(GetValue(ShowHideProperty))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            SetValue(ShowHideProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Below is the full vb code

```
Public ReadOnly ShowHideFirstButtonProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHideFirstButton", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf onShowHideFirstButtonChanged)))


Public Property ShowHideFirstButton As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(ShowHideFirstButtonProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(ShowHideFirstButtonProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub OnShowHideFirstButtonChanged()
    If ShowHideFirstButton Then
        First.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'First being the button whose visibility is to be changed
    Else
        First.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Krishna.  Many Thanks  I have added an edit to your answer showing the final code that I arrived at (which appears to work) Many thanks for your help.  The only thing which I have had to do is change the default Public Shared declaration for the Dependency to be just Public otherwise one couldn't call the OnShowHideFirstButtonChanged menthod.